# Multiple CSS background images ? How to place?

Tags: css, image, background, tumblr

total newbie here.

*http://makimaki45.tumblr.com/*

Does anyone know how to put another background image at the right of the description and the left of the first post column ? How to put it exactly somewhere ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

how about a new div with style similar to this:

```
  <style>
    .mydiv {
      position:absolute; 
      left:0px;
      top:0px;
      background-color:#fff; /*obviously insert your background here */
      height:400px;
      width:200px;
    }
  </style>
```